# Update .properties or .yml file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, properties-file

Requirement: I have to update `.properties or .yml` file. Which is in parent module.
I have created spring boot custom library to get values from parent `.properties or .yml` and communicate to third service to get Json data. That contain password. This password I have to update to properties file.

**Our application not supporting spring-cloud. Reason for going custom library**

```
From parent application
datasource:
     url: jdbc:postgresql:URL
     username: CURRENTUSER
     password: CURRENT
```

Now i have to update property say **'datasoucrce.password=CURRENT' to 'datasoucrce.password=UPDATEDPASSWORD'**
in custom library.

```
From Custom Library application
    datasource:
         url: jdbc:postgresql:URL
         username: UPDATEDUSER
         password: UPDATEDPASSWORD
```

I have only one .yml file. But I have to update inherited `datasoucrce.password="CURRENT"` to `datasoucrce.password="UPDATEDPASSWORD"` This UPDATEDPASSWORD (value). I am getting from API call
Any help?

Comment: is the indentation different in the two files? because the indentation in your code is not the same and that may have an effect in yaml

Comment: I have only one .yml file. But I have to update inherted 
```datasoucrce.password="CURRENT"``` to ```datasoucrce.password="UPDATEDPASSWORD"```
This UPDATEDPASSWORD (value). I am getting from 1 service call.
Hope now my question it clear

Answer (score 0):

The [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) format is XML based and looks completely different from the [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) format.

But you don't even have the latter as both documents will not load as you cannot have a multiline plain (i.e. unquoted) scalar be the key of a mapping entry.

Even if the first line of you documents is commented out, you would still not have `datasoucrce` as key of the root level mapping you would get after loading, but `datasource`.